# How to customize the error code and response body from Istio on AuthorizationPolicy deny?

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, custom-error-handling

When a request is denied the reply back is:

```
HTTP 403
RBAC: access denied
```

Is there any way of customising this error to have a different status code and reply body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is currently not possible with Istio API, however there is a [feature request for that on Github](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/10543).

There is also [a workaround using an envoy filter](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/10543#issuecomment-921179277) to customize that response.

Note, however, that Envoy filters are low-level constructs compared to Istio API and [Istio doc](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/) says:

> This feature must be used with care, as incorrect configurations could potentially destabilize the entire mesh.